# Maven jar dependency issue package not found on OpenShift server

Tags: java, maven, openshift

I'm getting a dependency issue with a jar I'm attempting to use.
I receive the following error

```
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project sparq: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/55846322500446673d000007/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/ServerQuery.java:[3,0] error: package com.github.koraktor.steamcondenser does not exist
remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/55846322500446673d000007/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/ServerQuery.java:[8,8] error: cannot find symbol
remote: [ERROR] class ServerQuery
remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/55846322500446673d000007/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/ServerQuery.java:[8,34] error: cannot find symbol
```

Here is the offending java file.

```
package helpers;

import com.github.koraktor.steamcondenser.*;

public class ServerQuery {

    public static String getPlayers() {
        SourceServer server = new SourceServer("66.150.155.152",27015);
        server.initialize();
        return server.toString();
    }
}
```

I've added the following dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>                                                                                                    
    <groupId>com.github.koraktor</groupId>                                                                      
    <artifactId>steam-condenser</artifactId>                                                                    
    <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also added the following action_hook pre_build script

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./app-root/repo/steam-condenser.jar -DgroupId=com.github.koraktor -DartifactId=steam-condenser -Dversion=1.3.9 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Here's the GitHub for the project
https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-java
And the website for it
http://koraktor.de/steam-condenser/usage/

Any ideas? Completely lost. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are including the jar file in your project already, trying to manage the dependency with Maven seems like overkill. You should be able to put the jar file in your project's lib directory like [this article](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399730-How-to-include-libraries-jar-files-in-your-java-application-without-using-Maven) describes. Then you won't need to configure that dependency in Maven at all.

I would use Maven for any dependencies that you want to download at the time your application is being built. Any jar files that you are checking into your project shouldn't need to be configured in Maven.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I've read that and tried it already. Eclipse isn't giving me any package not found issues, either. It's only when I try to deploy to the server. I guess I'll have to ask OpenShift.

Comment: You tried it already and it didn't work? What exactly happened?

Answer (score -1):

Just by looking at the question and the excerpts provided, I believe you are struggling with the basics of Maven. If I understand the situation correctly you have a library (which is not written by you):

- once added to your project as a Maven dependency. This seems reasonable if you want to use it.
- once the source code of the library incorrectly added to your own Java project.

  remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/55846322500446673d000007/app-root/runtime/repo/**src/main/java/ServerQuery.java**:[3,0] error: **package com.github.koraktor.steamcondenser** does not exist

Based on the errormessage above it seems you have copied one of the sourcefiles from the library into your project. This is now causing problems. The main one is that without your source-folder (src/main/java) correctly representing the package structure declared in the source file (com.github...) it cannot be compiled. Hence the errormessage:

```
package com.github.koraktor.steamcondenser does not exist.
```

First of all you need to remove this copy-pasted file entirely an just use the dependency-management feature of Maven to get the library on classpath. After that just follow the examples given by the author of the library using the link you have already found (http://koraktor.de/steam-condenser/usage/).

Comment: Not sure if I interpreted this correctly, but I'm not copy and pasting code from the library. I'm trying to use some of the classes and methods provided by the library, one of which is SourceServer, in a servlet that's then being called in a scriptlet (which I did not provide). My apologies for being unclear. What's interesting is that Eclipse doesn't complain about the package not being found. It's only when I deploy to the server!